# Boolean Blinking LED for Labview

Tags: boolean, labview

I want to make my LED blink when I click Yes on my two button dialog. I had referred many other vi to do the similar process using "Select" function. But I have no idea why my "s" terminal won't become true when I click Yes in my case structure.

My vi:

[image: The vi in question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes true when you press "yes" But in next iteration executes false state of the first call case and it becomes false after second iteration. Put shift register to remember your "yes" decision after 1st iteration. Also have a look on my comments: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pwx9fv1v70b9ttb/RnhZN.png?dl=0